# Условия передачи php (method="post" )

Tags: php

Отправляю информацию на почту через сервер.

Скрипт выглядит примерно так:

```
if (isset($_POST['ok'])){
//input type="checkbox"
    $chek_1=$_POST['chek_1'];
    $chek_2=$_POST['chek_2'];
    $chek_2=$_POST['chek_3'];
//input type="text"
    $val_1=$_POST['val_1'];
    $val_2=$_POST['val_2'];
    $val_3=$_POST['val_3'];

$messages=
    $chek_1; $val_1;"\n"
    $chek_2; $val_2;"\n"
    $chek_3; $val_3;"\n"
```

Значение chek_1 - это

A val_1 - это  у него по умолчанию стоит какое-то значение.

Логически эти input между собой связаны.

Теперь сам вопрос:
Если значение первого (chek_1) input = off (т.е. не отмечен) как не передавать (val_1)?

Comment: `$messages=    $chek_1.; .$val_1.;"\n"` это вообще что за синтаксис такой? И тут `$val_1==$_POST['val_1']` равенство а не присваивание

Comment: @teran А как по вашему присвоить этой переменной булево значение ?

Comment: Торопился написать вопрос и немного напортачил, сейчас исправил.

Comment: если вы таким образом хотите переменной присвоить булево значение то оно всегда будет `true`. Потому что  `$val_1=='off'` и `$val_1=='on'` всегда будет `true`.Вам надо по другому `$val_1 = ($_POST['val_1']==='off') ? false : true;`

Comment: ' второго (val_1) ' ? Поясните разве второй `val` у вас не  `$val_2` ?

Comment: Нужно чтобы письмо приходило следующего вида: ИМЯ (chek_1) - ЗНАЧЕНИЕ (val_1). Если chek_1 не был отмечен, то и val_1 не передается.

Comment: Исправил момент сбивающий с толку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по вашему вопросу и комментариев `$_POST['chek_n']` принимает либо `off`,если `checkbox` не установлен,либо то что вам нужно.

Ваш исправленный вариант :

```
if (isset($_POST['ok'])){
//input type="checkbox"
    $chek_1 = ($_POST['chek_1'] == 'off') ? false : $_POST['chek_1'];
    $chek_2 = ($_POST['chek_2'] == 'off') ? false : $_POST['chek_2'];
    $chek_3 = ($_POST['chek_3'] == 'off') ? false : $_POST['chek_3'];
//input type="text"
    $val_1 = $_POST['val_1'];
    $val_2 = $_POST['val_2'];
    $val_2 = $_POST['val_3'];

$messages  = ($chek_1) ? $chek_1.' = '.$val_1."\n" : '';
$messages .= ($chek_2) ? $chek_2.' = '.$val_2."\n" : '';
$messages .= ($chek_3) ? $chek_3.' = '.$val_3."\n" : '';
```

Comment: вы код пишите ради количества строк их длины что ли?

Comment: @teran По вопросу автора можно определить что он новичок в этом деле.И сэкономить пару строк могло вызвать у автора дискомфорт.Надеюсь и на ваш вопрос я ответил :)

Comment: дело не в экономии пары строк, а использовании тернарных операторов, где не надо, это только серьезно усложняет читабельность и понимание кода. Если хотите человека чему то научить - напишите более качественный ответ, возможно на более высоком уровне чем спрашивающий владеет, и разъясните свой код. Иначе так и будет сидеть не развивая свои навыки.

Comment: @teran "дело не в экономии пары строк, а использовании тернарных операторов, где не надо" ? А где надо ?

Comment: формально у вас тут вложенный тернарный оператор, у которого 3 из 4х веток не приводят ни какому к результату. это ненормально.

Comment: @teran " у которого 3 из 4х веток не приводят ни какому к результату" ? о чём вы ? где вы такое разглядели ?

Comment: да, с 4мя погорячился. но `false` и `' ' ` это бесполезные вещи. я не вижу смысла писать такие портянки, они не продуктивны, их сложно понимать и поддерживать. в данном случае обычный `if` куда нагляднее. Ладно. дискуссию закончим на сим, я свое видение данного кода в соседнем ответе привел.

Comment: @teran Негорячитесь :) это элементарная вещь на которую я не хочу уделять внимание.Рад был общению.Удачи !

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативный вариант записи кода из соседнего ответа.

```
if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
    $msgs = [];
    foreach([1,2,3] as $i){
        if($_POST["chek_$i"] == 'off') continue;
        $msgs[] = $_POST["chek_$i"].'='.$_POST["val_$i"];
    }
    $messages = implode("\n", $msgs);
}
```